# simple drawing does not get display using Border container in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

just started a simple drawing tool in Flex to get used to the graphics coding in Flex. Got a problem in the beginning itself.

Here I am using Border Container as a drawing area (Flex 4) instead of Canvas and I am drawing simple dot on Mousemove event. Yep very simple basic thing. But I don't see the drawn dots in the border container area. But I see the Mouse Event getting fired. No Idea what am missing.

Below is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.containers.Canvas;
        import mx.skins.Border;

        import spark.components.BorderContainer;

        protected function init():void
        {
            var whiteboard:BorderContainer = new BorderContainer();
            whiteboard.width = 1000;
            whiteboard.height = 600;                
            whiteboard.addEventListener
                  (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,whiteboard_mouseMoveHandler);
            this.addElement(whiteboard);

        }

        protected function  whiteboard_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {               

            var graph:Graphics =
                          (event.currentTarget as BorderContainer).graphics;                    
            graph.beginFill(0x000000);
            graph.drawCircle(event.localX,event.localY,3);
            trace("x:"+event.localX+":y:"+event.localY);                
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BorderContainer` is most likely not expecting you to draw on it's graphics object. I haven't looked at the code for `BorderContainer` lately, but I recall someone else having a similar problem.

Since a `BorderContainer` draws a border around it's contents, it's most likely using it's `graphics`object to draw that border. So you shouldn't try to use the `graphics` property of the border container to draw on.

Instead, add a `UIComponent` or some other Flex object to the border container, and then draw your graphics on that object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a skin and draw in the skin. That's the whole behaviour/skin separation is for.